# What is the best way to fetch the NFT image along with metadata?

Tags: mpl-token-metadata

Currently, the following call will return nft metadata that contains uri.

```
export async function fetchAsset(
  context: Pick<Context, 'eddsa' | 'programs' | 'rpc'>,
  mint: PublicKey,
): Promise<Asset | undefined> {
  const metadata = findMetadataPda(context, { mint });
  const edition = findMasterEditionPda(context, { mint });

  const [mintAccount, metadataAccount, editionAccount] =
    (await context.rpc.getAccounts([mint, metadata[0], edition[0]])) as [
      MaybeRpcAccount,
      MaybeRpcAccount,
      MaybeRpcAccount,
    ];

  if (!metadataAccount.exists) {
    return;
  }

  assertAccountExists(mintAccount, 'Mint');

  const mintData = deserializeMint(mintAccount);
  const metadataData = deserializeMetadata(metadataAccount);

  let editionData: Edition | undefined;

  // Check if the asset is an NFT.
  if (
    editionAccount.exists &&
    unwrapOption(mintData.mintAuthority) == editionAccount.publicKey
  ) {
    editionData = deserializeEdition(editionAccount);
  }

  return {
    publicKey: mint,
    mint: mintData,
    metadata: metadataData,
    edition: editionData,
  };
}
```

Is there a way to fetch all the nft images in the same call instead of using the uri one by one?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the DAS api from triton, helius or metaplex for example. Here are the helius docs for it:
https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/digital-asset-standard-das-api

This is how you can load up to 1000 nfts at once:

```
async function getAssetsByOwner(ownerAddress: PublicKey) {
    const sortBy = {
      sortBy: "created",
      sortDirection: "asc",
    };
    const limit = 1000;
    const page = 1;
    const before = "";
    const after = "";
    const allAssetsOwned = await CONNECTION.getAssetsByOwner(
      ownerAddress.toBase58(),
      sortBy,
      limit,
      page,
      before,
      after
    );

    setNftState(allAssetsOwned);
    console.log(allAssetsOwned);
  }
```

Here is a react example of it:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana_game_preset/blob/main/app/contexts/NftProvider.tsx

Comment: Is there a way to get Helius to return the `programmableConfig` as well?

Comment: I dont know. Best check their docs or their discord.